# Finding all invertible elements of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to solve the following exercise:

> Let $A^{X}$ be the ring of maps $f: X \rightarrow A$ where $X$ is a given set and $A$ is a given ring with the operations
> $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> (f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) \\
> (f g)(x)=f(x) g(x)
> \end{array}
> $$
> Find its invertible elements.

This is what I've got so far: 
We know an element $x\in X$ is invertible if there exists $y\in X$ such that $x y=y x=e$, where $e$ is the neutral element ($0$ for the sum and $1$ for multiplication).

Therefore we want to find $g: X \rightarrow A$ such that $f(x)g(x)=1=g(x)f(x)$
This gives us that $g(x)=f(x)^{-1}$ 
I don't know what to do next, any ideas?

Comment: Hint: It might help to first identify the unit element in the ring of maps. Also note that the condition $f(x) g(x) = 1 = g(x) f(x)$ as you wrote it is a little ambiguous. Do you mean that this should hold for some $x\in X$ or all $x\in X$?

Comment: Also check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206194/units-of-a-function-ring) which deals with the case where $X = [0, 1]$ and $A = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A map $f$ is a unit if and only if $f(x)$ is a unit $\forall x \in X$.

Comment: You [deleted and reposted this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4117701/29335), which is bad form. In doing so you shed earlier feedback in the form of comments and votes.  It may not have been your intention, but this will be perceived as you attempting to circumvent moderation. The right thing to do instead would have been to EDIT the question to add the content you added here. This would have been perfectly fine since no solutions were given yet.

Comment: "That gives us $g(x)=f(x)^{-1}$" It looks like you don't realize this puts constraints on how $f$ can behave. If $f(x)=0$, for some $x$, the right hand of that equality has no meaning.  The whole answer is not far off, you just have to consider this simple restriction.